# Scraping a Page within a Page sometimes doesn't enter the second Page

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using the following Spider here:

```
import scrapy

questions = {}

class SovSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'StackOverflow'
    allowed_domains = ['stackoverflow.com']
    start_urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions']

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.css('a.question-hyperlink::attr(href)').extract():

            yield scrapy.Request(url=response.urljoin(link), callback=self.parse_questions)

            yield scrapy.Request(url=response.urljoin(response.css('a[rel="next"]::attr(href)').extract_first()), callback=self.parse)


    def parse_questions(self, response):
        questions["title"] = response.css('a.question-hyperlink::text').extract_first()
        questions["user"] = response.css('.user-details a::text').extract_first()

        yield scrapy.Request(url=response.urljoin(response.css('.user-details a::attr(href)').extract_first()), callback=self.parse_user)

        yield questions

    def parse_user(self, response):
        questions["user_reputation"] = response.css('div.reputation::text').extract_first().strip()
```

trying to ***`Practice`*** Scraping a Page, Then getting a URL from the same Page to Scrape its Page `[Page1(Scraped) -[Page1[Url-Inside]]> Page2(Scrape)]`

What the Spider do is the following:

1. Scrape `Questions Page` URLs
2. Scrape `Question Title` From the
   entered Page by the **`URLs`**
3. Scrape `User Reputation` From the
   User's Page entered by a **`Scraped URL`** of `Question`

So for Example, My Question here is Supposed to give me the following:

```
{"title": "Scraping a Page within a Page sometimes doesn't enter the second Page", "user": "Toleo", "user_reputation": 455}
```

The problem is that almost **3/4** of the scraped items returns only the `parse_question` part like this

```
{"title": "Scraping a Page within a Page sometimes doesn't enter the second Page", "user": "Toleo"}
```

And sometimes not, What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you yield the request for `parse_user` at the same time as you yield `questions` but Item and Request are handled by different middlewares so they will not be executed one after the other.

You'd better send the first part of questions to `parse_user` by using meta and only yield `questions` in `parse_user`

```
def parse_questions(self, response):
    questions = {}

    questions["title"] = response.css('a.question-hyperlink::text').extract_first()
    questions["user"] = response.css('.user-details a::text').extract_first()

    yield scrapy.Request(url=response.urljoin(response.css('.user-details a::attr(href)').extract_first()),
                         callback=self.parse_user,
                         meta={'questions': questions})

def parse_user(self, response):
    questions = response.meta.get('questions')
    questions["user_reputation"] = response.css('div.reputation::text').extract_first().strip()
    yield questions
```

You'd better create a new variable `questions` at each call of `parse_questions` like above because it is not supposed to be a global variable.

Moreover should correct `parse` like this

```
def parse(self, response):
    for link in response.css('a.question-hyperlink::attr(href)').extract():

        yield scrapy.Request(url=response.urljoin(link), callback=self.parse_questions)

    yield scrapy.Request(url=response.urljoin(response.css('a[rel="next"]::attr(href)').extract_first()), callback=self.parse)
```

Because you yield a request for the next page for every link on one page, which is not so much problematique because scrapy as a dupefilter but it would be probably more effective

Comment: That worked! What does `meta` do exactly? copy the list and move it to the other `def`?

Comment: @Toleo meta allows you to carry data from one response to another one. It is very usefil when you need to do serveral requests to build one `Item` (like here one for questions, one for users) because you can transfer the data you got in the first request to the second request and so far so on.